# prepositional phrases in passive voice

Tags: passive-voice, prepositional-phrases, active-voice

If we use a prepositional "by phrase" then it is passive form but if we use other prepositions such as "to, with" etc., then is the verb in passive or active form?

For example:

Actives:

- They told me a secret
- He tells me to come.

Passives:

1. A secret was told to me by them = I was told a secret to me by them.
2. I am told to come by him.

My question is without the "by phrase" for example in

1. I was told a secret to me
2. I am told to come.

Are these in passive or active voice?

Comment: If your question is: _Is a clause in the passive voice required to contain a prepositional phrase beginning with "by"?_ then the answer is "no." Your last two sentences are in the passive voice.